# Flume creating an empty line at the end of output file in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, flume, flume-ng, bigdata

Currently I am using Flume version : 1.5.2.

Flume creating an empty line at the end of each output file in HDFS   which causing  row counts, file sizes & check sum are not matching for source and destination files.

I tried by overriding the default values of parameters roolSize, batchSize and appendNewline but still its not working.

Also flume changing EOL from CRLF(Source file) to LF(outputfile) this also causing file size to differ

Below are related flume agent configuration parameters I'm using

```
 agent1.sources = c1
 agent1.sinks = c1s1
 agent1.channels = ch1

 agent1.sources.c1.type = spooldir
 agent1.sources.c1.spoolDir = /home/biadmin/flume-test/sourcedata1
 agent1.sources.c1.bufferMaxLineLength = 80000
 agent1.sources.c1.channels = ch1
 agent1.sources.c1.fileHeader = true 
 agent1.sources.c1.fileHeaderKey = file
 #agent1.sources.c1.basenameHeader = true
 #agent1.sources.c1.fileHeaderKey = basenameHeaderKey
 #agent1.sources.c1.filePrefix = %{basename}
 agent1.sources.c1.inputCharset = UTF-8
 agent1.sources.c1.decodeErrorPolicy = IGNORE
 agent1.sources.c1.deserializer= LINE
 agent1.sources.c1.deserializer.maxLineLength =  50000
 agent1.sources.c1.deserializer=
 org.apache.flume.sink.solr.morphline.BlobDeserializer$Builder
agent1.sources.c1.interceptors = a b
agent1.sources.c1.interceptors.a.type  =     
org.apache.flume.interceptor.TimestampInterceptor$Builder
agent1.sources.c1.interceptors.b.type =
org.apache.flume.interceptor.HostInterceptor$Builder
agent1.sources.c1.interceptors.b.preserveExisting = false
agent1.sources.c1.interceptors.b.hostHeader = host

agent1.channels.ch1.type = memory
agent1.channels.ch1.capacity = 1000
agent1.channels.ch1.transactionCapacity = 1000
agent1.channels.ch1.batchSize = 1000
agent1.channels.ch1.maxFileSize = 2073741824
agent1.channels.ch1.keep-alive = 5
agent1.sinks.c1s1.type = hdfs
agent1.sinks.c1s1.hdfs.path = hdfs://bivm.ibm.com:9000/user/biadmin/
flume/%y-%m-%d/%H%M
agent1.sinks.c1s1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
agent1.sinks.c1s1.hdfs.filePrefix = %{file}
agent1.sinks.c1s1.hdfs.fileSuffix =.csv
agent1.sinks.c1s1.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
agent1.sinks.c1s1.hdfs.maxOpenFiles = 10
agent1.sinks.c1s1.hdfs.rollSize = 67000000
agent1.sinks.c1s1.hdfs.rollCount = 0
#agent1.sinks.c1s1.hdfs.rollInterval = 0
agent1.sinks.c1s1.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
agent1.sinks.c1s1.channel = ch1
#agent1.sinks.c1s1.hdfs.codeC = snappyCodec
agent1.sinks.c1s1.hdfs.serializer = text
agent1.sinks.c1s1.hdfs.serializer.appendNewline = false
```

hdfs.serializer.appendNewline not fixed the issue.
Can anyone please check and suggest..

Answer (score 0):

Replace the below line in your flume agent.

```
agent1.sinks.c1s1.serializer.appendNewline = false
```

with the following line and let me know how it goes.

```
agent1.sinks.c1s1.hdfs.serializer.appendNewline = false
```

Comment: Thanks Rajesh for looking into this. I am still getting file size difference as shown below

Comment: I'm still getting difference in file size. biadmin@bivm:~/Desktop/work/flume-test/sourcedata1> hadoop fs -copyToLocal hdfs://bivm.ibm.com:9000/user/biadmin/flume/home/biadmin/Desktop/work/flume-test/sourcedata1/TermDefinition.csv.1452750041843.csv 
biadmin@bivm:~/Desktop/work/flume-test/sourcedata1> ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 biadmin biadmin 754 Jan 14 00:42 TermDefinition.csv.1452750041843.csv
-rwxrw-rw- 1 biadmin biadmin 767 Jan 14 00:06 TermDefinition.csv.COMPLETED
biadmin@bivm:~/Desktop/work/flume-test/sourcedata1>

Comment: My observations is that EOL is getting changed from CRLF to LF because of this File size is getting differed. I am unable to share my conf file as this comment section has limitation on no.of.characters to be filled. Could you please suggest how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
agent1.sinks.c1s1.hdfs.serializer = text
agent1.sinks.c1s1.hdfs.serializer.appendNewline = false
```

with

```
agent1.sinks.c1s1.serializer = text
agent1.sinks.c1s1.serializer.appendNewline = false
```

Difference is that serializer settings are not set on hdfs prefix but directly on sink name.

Flume documentation should have some example on that as I also got into issues because I didn't spot that serializer is set on different level of property name.

More informations about Hdfs sink can be found here:
https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#hdfs-sink